remote server B is mounted to vscode folder on server A . Running as a different user on Remote B, how to initiate vscode debug from command line?
VS Code is installed and working great in a workspace on (Linux) Server A. (Access to Server A is via the VSCode Remote Development extension.)  The workflow is for the user on Server A open a terminal window and dzdu su to a different user and ssh to (Linux) Server B. The code that diff user runs on Server B is the code in the VS Code workspace on Server A - mounted as a folder in Server B-  while the data and other required items are on Server B. Is it possible to invoke the VS Code debugger as diff user from Server B, since it has access to the VS Code workspace via the mounted drive? How would this be achieved?  Or is there a way to invoke the debugger from Server A but run the debugger ssh'ed to server B as diff user?
